# Arquillian ApplicationDescriptor issues

Tags: java, websphere, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to get Arquillian tests running on Websphere 8.5 Remote. Injection is not working:
Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.arquillian.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>arquillian-tutorial</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


    <!-- Properties -->



    <properties>
        <was_home>C:/usr_local2/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer</was_home>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>build-server</id>
            <properties>
                <was_home>${WAS85_HOME}</was_home>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
                <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0-alpha-6</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-was-remote-8.5</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-depchain</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-alpha-6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- com.ibm.websphere -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.websphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>was-public</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${was_home}/dev/was_public.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.websphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>ws-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${was_home}/runtimes/com.ibm.ws.admin.client_8.5.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have EJB:

```
package org.arquillian.example;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import java.io.PrintStream;

/**
 * A component for creating personal greetings.
 */
@Singleton
public class Greeter {
    private PhraseBuilder phraseBuilder;

    @Inject
    public Greeter(PhraseBuilder phraseBuilder) {
        this.phraseBuilder = phraseBuilder;
    }

    public void greet(PrintStream to, String name) {
        to.println(createGreeting(name));
    }

    public String createGreeting(String name) {
        return phraseBuilder.buildPhrase("hello", name);
    }
}
```

And I have my Arquillian test:

```
    package org.arquillian.example;

import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.Archive;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.EmptyAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.StringAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class GreeterTest {

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
        WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class).addClass(Greeter.class).addClass(PhraseBuilder.class)
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
        System.out.println(war.toString(true));
        return war;

    }

    @Inject
    Greeter greeter;

    @EJB
    Greeter greeter2;

    @Test
    public void shouldBeInjectedCDI() {
        Assert.assertNotNull("CDI injection is not working", greeter);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldBeInjectedEJB() {
        Assert.assertNotNull("EJB injection is not working", greeter2);
    }

    @Test
    public void should_create_greeting() {
        Assert.assertEquals("Hello, Earthling!",
                greeter.createGreeting("Earthling"));
        greeter.greet(System.out, "Earthling");
    }
}
```

but once I start tests they all failed.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.arquillian.example.GreeterTest.should_create_greeting(GreeterTest.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$6$1.invoke(Arquillian.java:301)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.LocalTestExecuter.execute(LocalTestExecuter.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.protocol.local.LocalContainerMethodExecutor.invoke(LocalContainerMethodExecutor.java:50)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.RemoteTestExecuter.execute(RemoteTestExecuter.java:109)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientTestExecuter.execute(ClientTestExecuter.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createTestContext(ContainerEventController.java:129)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:102)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:65)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.test(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:111)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$6.evaluate(Arquillian.java:294)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:269)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:193)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:345)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:49)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:207)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:155)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

I have tried many things. @ApplicationScoped, @SessionScoped on Greeter class. Could someone help me out?

Edit:
Here is the archive

```
2adbe911-ddef-42b5-bbfe-4d13fe620acd.war:
/META-INF/
/META-INF/beans.xml
/WEB-INF/
/WEB-INF/beans.xml
/WEB-INF/classes/
/WEB-INF/classes/org/
/WEB-INF/classes/org/arquillian/
/WEB-INF/classes/org/arquillian/example/
/WEB-INF/classes/org/arquillian/example/Greeter.class
/WEB-INF/classes/org/arquillian/example/PhraseBuilder.class
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `beans.xml` file to enable CDI. For web modules it should be in `WEB-INF`, for ejb modules in `META-INF` folder.

Comment: Should not following line do it?
.addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")

Comment: @user831217 Yes it should. Sorry didn't noticed that. And from your assertions is `@EJB` working? Or both `@EJB` and `@Inject` are not working?

Comment: Nothing works on Websphere. I tested it with Weld and it goes without issues.